# WooCommerce max quantity per category

Tags: woocommerce, plugins

I'm looking for a plugin which allows me to set the maximum quantity of a specific product category.

Example: BookA and BookB belong to "SpecialBooks". The user can only buy 3 SpecialBooks. Either

**2 x BookA and 1 x BookB**, or

**3 x BookA but no BookB**, etc.

Most of the plugins I've found allow me to set the max quantity on the product category, but this allows the user to buy 3 x BookA and 3 x BookB.

Comment: I would suggest programming this. Give it a try and ask for help in case you're stuck!

Comment: @Mr.Jo I'd be able to code it myself, but since the budget is tight, I was hoping for an existing plugin.

Comment: Our time as well! I dont want to be rude but we're spending our time here as well! Give it a try and update your question if you get stuck. For me it sounds work for less an hour.

Comment: @Mr.Jo your answer is not rude, but makes no sense at all. No one forces you to spend your time here, if you don't want to. Sure, it may be an hour of work, initially.. but did you consider the time that needs to be spent in testing and keeping the code up-to-date with the latest WooCommerce updates?